# Make a HTTP GET request in java?

Tags: java, android

Anybody knows how to make a http request in java for this?

Create a new class (for example LatchSDK.java) extending Latch.java. This class should override HTTP_GET method with your own implementation to perform HTTP requests as you usually perform them in your project.

```
 public class LatchSDK extends Latch{

      @Override
      public JsonElement HTTP_GET(String URL, Map<String, String>headers) {
           //Your implementation here
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with the [HttpURLConnection](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) class. There are plenty of examples online on how to apply it.

Comment: Thanks, but how I can send the Map<String, String>headers?

Comment: You should be able to use setRequestProperty for this:

    `for (String header : headers.keySet())
    {
        httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty(header, headers.get(header);
    }`

Comment: Thanks again, but I get an inputstream and I need a JsonElement. I search but I dont found how to do it